# Using separate model methods to manage transactions

Tags: php, codeigniter, transactions

If i’ve got 2(or more) model methods which do (for example, in billing system) enrolling/withdrawing, and one controller’s method that calls 2(or more) of these model methods.

Is it a good way(maybe, any suggestions how to do it better) to write/use 2model methods like these:

```
public function start_transaction(){
    $this->db->trans_start();
}

public function end_transaction(){
   $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

And call in controller’s method:

```
   public function smth(){
       //something
       $this->model->start_transaction();
       $this->model->enroll();
       //something else
       $this->model->withdraw();
       $this->model->end_transaction();
   }
```

Will transaction be reversed, if model's withdraw() method fails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly new to CodeIgniter, but I've been doing a fair amount of transactional work in my project.

However, I've been using the DataMapper Overzealous ORM library - and handling transactions using that code library.

So DMZ code I've been writing (caution - may not be best practice) would look something like:

```
public function smth() {
  $model->trans_begin();
  // assuming method returns boolean
  $enroll_success = $model->enroll();
  //something else
  // assuming method returns boolean
  $withdraw_success = $model->withdraw();
  if ($enroll_success && $withdraw_success && $model->trans_status() === TRUE)
  {
    $model->trans_commit();
  }
  else
  {
    $model->trans_rollback();
  }
}
```

I'm also assuming that the "something else" happening in your controller prevents you from creating a single method in your model that would just handle both the enroll & withdraw functions in a transaction.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i can't use a single method (otherwise- i didn't ask such dumb questions :)).

One more question: using standard CI's active record, it seems i can't call(from controller's method) - like you do - $model->trans_begin(). ? (so, am i 'doomed' to use additional functions - like in my question?)

Comment: I figured... though since I started this project, all I feel like I've been doing is asking dumb questions so thought I would double check. :) 

In the end, isn't the DMZ $model->trans_begin() the same thing as you having a separate method in your model start_transaction()? 

I adopted DMZ pretty quickly, so I don't have as much experience with just straight CI active record, but it seems like it would work. Do you have a sandbox where you could do some testing with this?

Comment: Yes, i've got sandbox and will test it.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure... would you mind posting your results back here? I'd like to have a better understanding of how the standard CI Active Record system would work in this situation.

Comment: Of course, if it makes sense. //not sure - i might post it as comment (or answer)?